# Denseness of $L^1\cap L^2$ in $L^p$ on R

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I need to show that $L^1\cap L^2$ is dense in $L^p$ for $p\in (1,2)$

I think one-way is to construct a sequence of function possibly simple in the intersection converging to any arbitrary function in $L^p$.

Also, I know a fact that, for all $ f\in L^p $ we can decompose them into $f_1+f_2$ where $f_1 \in L^r ,f_2\in L^s$ such that $p\in (r,s)$. Can this be helpful in someway.

Any suggestions will be helpful!!
Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to work "from scratch", you can use that lower $L^p$'s are dense as can be seen by trimming an arbitrarily small amount of the tails, while higher $L^p$'s are dense by trimming out an arbitrarily small neighborhood of each singularity. Note that before that you need to check that the intersection is even a subset of $L^p$ to begin with, which requires some interpolation inequality.

Comment: Do you need to show that $L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a subset of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$? Or is this already clear?

Comment: what measure space are you using?

Comment: Yeah, You are right  we first need to show it's a subset. A hint would do @StarBug

Comment: By your statement do you mean dense in itself and what does lower and higher Lp's mean ?@Ian

Comment: Depending on how exactly you define $L^p$, you typically obtain at the outset that either the space of simple functions or the space $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p$. But both of these spaces are subspaces of $L^1\cap L^2$, so if you know that $L^1\cap L^2\subset L^p$, you are done. The decomposition you mention at the end, however, more or less establishes this inclusion.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana I mean that $L^1 \cap L^p$ is dense in $L^p$ if $p>1$ as can be seen by cutting off the tail of a given $L^p$ function if necessary, while $L^2 \cap L^p$ is dense in $L^p$ if $p<2$ as can be seen by removing singularities if necessary. Thus the intersection of the two is also dense in $L^p$. Finally $L^1 \cap L^2 \cap L^p = L^1 \cap L^2$ by an interpolation inequality.

Comment: But using simple functions is a more direct way to do it, once you know $L^1 \cap L^2 \subset L^p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a function in $ L^p$ and let 
$$
f_n\colon x\mapsto f(x)\mathbf{1}_{[-n,n]}(x)\mathbf{1}_{[-n,n] }\left(\left\lvert f(x)\right\rvert\right).
$$
The point of the indicator functions is that in general, $f$ has no reason to belong to $L^1$ or to $L^2$; if $f$ was bounded we would know that $f$ would be also in $L^2$ because $f^2\leqslant \lvert f\rvert^p \lVert f\rVert_\infty^{2-p}$; if $f$ had bounded support, we would know that $f\in L^1$. Now $f_n$ has both features hence $f_n$ belongs to $L^1\cap L^2$ and by applying the dominated convergence theorem to the sequence $\left(\left\lvert f_n-f\right\rvert^p\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$, we can show that $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$.

Comment: Is that a notation for characteristic function? @DavideGiraudo

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Can you just elaborate the fact of using product of two charactrstic functions, how does this actually help and thought process behind the construction? @DavideGiraudo

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana I have added some explanation.

Comment: That was really helpful@DavideGiraudo